# Is it useful to use mediator pattern with MVC?

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller

The question is about ideology of the MVC design pattern. By definition, the view is communicating with the controller directly. For instance, in `JSF` as well as `ASP.NET web-forms`, we can bind the property of the controller to a specific area of a web-page. But in this case we're doing that by directly wirte an expression like

```
<h:outputText value="#{partnerController.lastAccessDate}"/>
```

Would it be useful to create a mediator between views and controllers? I need, for instance, "send a message" to a several controller in a specific way.

Comment: In our application we follow the approach of only calling view-beans from the JSF view to have a clear boundary to the rest of the system - which means that JSF files refer to classes which have JSF scopes and JSF specific technology - which on their turn refer to JSF-independent technology themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a traditional web application where a JSP page (or PHP or some other HTML generator) generates a form which is filled by the user and posted back to the server, this does not make a lot of sence. The posted form is sent directly to a controller which handels the data.

In fat client environment this makes a lot fo sence. The fat client can be something like SWING or a JavaScript framework like Angular. Here the controller acutally is a mediator. What it does is often called data binding. It makes sure the data entered into the GUI is stored in the business objects which gets eventually sent accros the wire or persisted.

Comment: BUt as I said I need to send the data to several controller and invoke several methods in these several controllers. Why doesn't it make a sense?

Comment: If you can call this controllers with sequential code in your first controller the diffrence would be to sequentially connect this controllers to the mediator and then let it distribute the data. That's replacing one static piece of code with an other which is more complex and harder to maintain.